# Already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core

I am experimenting with EF7 beta 4 in combination with Azure web apps. Strangely:
1. A local web server / local db setup works;
2. A local web server / azure db setup works;
3. But: the Azure web server with azure db setup does not work. This results in the following infamous exception:

`InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

The connectionstring I use is as follows (currently the same on local web server and Azure web server):

`Server=...database.windows.net,1433;Database=...;User ID=...;Password=...;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

What do I have to do to get it running?

Comment: It sounds like the `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` part isn't making its way onto the Azure web server.

Comment: Try using beta5 and see if the problem persists.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServer/7.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when using Azure SQL Database.

My web.config files had the same flag in relevant connection strings. Everything worked fine locally but it didn't work when I published my solution into azure as web app.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

The reason is that web.config files might be overwritten in your publishing profile. You need to add that setting explicitly like below:

[image: Publish Web]

[image: Advanced settings]